# primefaces DataExporter ignore columns that have h:link

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

the primefaces DataExporter ignores the the column where I use  to link the result.

```
<p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Brand" />
            </f:facet>
         <h:link outcome="pretty:carBrand-page">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
         </h:link>
 </p:column>
```

How can I get the brand also exported, without href ?
Thanks